# JHipster executable war not executable in combination with Atmosphere

Tags: java, spring-boot, atmosphere, jhipster

When generating a fresh application with Atmosphere enabled everything seems to work fine. But when packaging the application in an executable war (as mentioned on the jhipster homepage) the application does not load properly.

It starts complaining about Atmosphere annotation scanning not able scan annotations from the atmosphere.jar within the executable jar with a MalformedURLException:

[WARN] org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAnnotationProcessor - Unable to scan annotation
java.net.MalformedURLException: Illegal character in opaque part at index 11: jar:file:C:\Development\test\target\test-0.1-SNAPSHOT.war!/WEB-INF/lib/atmosphere-runtime-2.1.0.jar!/org/atmosphere/annota
tion/

I have only generated a fresh project with Atmosphere enablef, packaged it and tried to run the executable war. Am I doing something wrong or am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The problem was fixed with an update to Atmosphere 2.2.2.

RequiresUnpack is not necessary and for further information take a look at the issue at jhipster-generator: https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/471